# Dynamically generated hero banner text running beneath 3 action cards when text section is too long, trying to add styling to prevent overlap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a dynamically generated hero banner that features a title and then body text underneath followed by three action cards that sit just over the bottom portion of the hero banner.

My issue is that whenever there's a hero banner that features longer body text it runs behind the action cards as shown here:

[image]

I tried adjusting the margin-bottom for the HeroText but it still just ran behind the cards. I'm trying to adjust the CardRow and the HeroText so that the CardRow pushes down in relation to how much text there is while still overlapping the HeroImage at the bottom but I'm stumped on how to do this.

I've added a CodeSandbox here:

[image: Edit wonderful-wright-tmgnu]

And included all of my code here:

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ContentContainer>
      <Container>
        <HeroElement>
          <HeroTitle>
            Modern competitive gaming with a huge nostalgic past built with
            traders and collectors in mind.
          </HeroTitle>
          <HeroText>
            Pokem ipsum dolor sit amet Seel Buizel Walrein Ditto Liepard
            Charmeleon. Flamethrower Staryu Nidoqueen Pallet Town Breloom
            Forretress Weepinbell. Sand-Attack Mienshao Slugma Slaking Luxio
            Rage Jesse. Grass Zigzagoon Hippopotas incididunt ut labore Magby
            Jesse Pokemon Heroes. Zephyr Badge Staravia Hitmontop Sharpedo
            Pidgeotto Venipede Gothitelle. Wing Attack Combusken Gothorita
            Zoroark Venusaur Haunter Sceptile. Pikachu Cascoon Rotom Whirlipede
            Cloyster.
          </HeroText>
        </HeroElement>
        <CardRowContainer>
          <Card>
            <CardTitle>More Information</CardTitle>
            <CardText>
              Get more information on your favorite Pokemon here
            </CardText>
            <ButtonContainer>
              <Icon></Icon>
            </ButtonContainer>
          </Card>
          <Card>
            <CardTitle>Team Leader Boards</CardTitle>
            <CardText>
              Check out the top Pokemon Go and Pokemon TCG players from around
              the world
            </CardText>
            <ButtonContainer>
              <Icon></Icon>
            </ButtonContainer>
          </Card>
          <Card>
            <CardTitle>TCG Catalog</CardTitle>
            <CardText>
              Request an exclusive catalog of limited edition and rare cards
              only available through The Pokemon Company!
            </CardText>
            <ButtonContainer>
              <Icon></Icon>
            </ButtonContainer>
          </Card>
        </CardRowContainer>
      </Container>
    </ContentContainer>
  );
}

const ContentContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;

  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
`;

const HeroElement = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(https://cdn5.qutee.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/heroUpload_433864841.jpg)
    0% 0% / cover no-repeat;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;

const HeroTitle = styled.h1`
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 48px auto 17px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 0.67em;
  margin-block-end: 0.67em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  text-align: center;
`;

const HeroText = styled.div`
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0px auto auto;
  color: white;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
`;

const CardRowContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin: -128px auto 22px;
  columns: auto 3;
  column-gap: 20px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
`;

const Card = styled.div`
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px;
  border-left: 4px solid rgb(217, 90, 90);
  padding: 20px 20px 15px;
  box-shadow: rgb(52 62 71 / 12%) 0px 3px 5px;
`;

const CardTitle = styled.div`
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px auto 8px 0px;
`;

const CardText = styled.div`
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0px auto 8px 0px;
`;

const ButtonContainer = styled.div`
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(217, 90, 90);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto auto 0px 0px;
`;

const Icon = styled.i`
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 12.5px 12.5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 0.8rem;
  right: 0.8rem;
  height: 0.8rem;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  ::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    top: 2px;
    right: -7px;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
`;
```

**EDIT**
After testing removing negative margin property and adding `position: relative` I lost the desired overlay effect of the card row at the bottom:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on debugging the code i found out that the cards have margin property in minus

[image]

as you can see the structure.

1. the cards wrapper is moved where the dynamic desc is being appended.
2. the style: adding `position: relative;` and removing the `margin: -(value);` to the same element.

hope this helped.

Comment: I know, it's not the prettiest but I used that to create the overlay effect haha. While ```position: relative``` works to fix the issue it also completely removes out the overlay.

Comment: can you update the codesandbox and show what you see?

Comment: Yeup just updated the original question with the output of that change

Comment: you will have re edit the structure and move the cardrowcontainer to HeroElement below HeroText

`</HeroText>
    <CardRowContainer>...rest Code</CardRowContainer>
 </HeroElement>
 `

Comment: Unfortunately that just creates the same problem stylistically. I think I have a better idea of what I'm going after that I'll ask in a separate question. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: same thing i have debugged and asked you to do you can see the image i shared there is DH (dynamic header) section and just below that your C (Card) section.

Comment: Oh wait I see! So with both of those changes together it works!